# Web crawler does not print

Tags: python, html, web-crawler, crawler4j

I'm working on my first web crawler and I cannot figure out how to get it to print results. There is not an error, but nothing displays.

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3

def extract_links():

```
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request('GET', 'http://www.drankbank.com/happy-hour-chicago.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

extract_links()

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are not accessing the data returned in the request.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
```

should be:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.data, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Very new to this.

Comment: Here is also the guide on urllib3 hope it helps http://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html